How to calculate the velocity of a point on a rigid body that is both translating and rotating?
I'm trying to figure out a problem involving the motion of a rigid body in 2D. The body has:

A translational velocity $\mathbf{v} = (v_x, v_y) $ at its center.
An angular velocity $\omega$ around its center.

I am trying to determine the velocity of a point $p$ that is fixed on the rigid body at the local position $(L_x, L_y)$ relative to the body's center.
Given both the translational and rotational components of motion, how do I calculate the total velocity of the point $p$?
Any help with the proper approach or geometric/physical reasoning for how to combine these components would be appreciated!
(It's not the same question as this one. My question is in the context of 2D movement in a plane, not a 1D rolling movement.)

This question is similar to: Why is the velocity different for different points on a rolling wheel?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

You are asking about the velocity kinematics. The 2D projection of the 3D equation $$\vec{v}_B = \vec{v}_A + \omega \times ( \vec{r}_B - \vec{r}_A )$$ is
$$ \pmatrix{ vx_B \\ vy_B } = \pmatrix{vx_A \\ vy_A} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\omega \\ \omega & 0 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{x_B-x_A \\ y_B-y_A} $$

So for your nomenclature and variables the velocity $(vx_P,vy_P)$ at the point P as is relates to the velocity $(vx_C,vy_C)$ at the center of mass is
$$ \pmatrix{ vx_P \\ vy_P } = \pmatrix{ vx_C - L_y \omega \\ vy_C + L_x \omega} $$
The geometric interpretation is take the velocity at the center as it is, and add the rotational component (light blue below) which is perpendicular to the distance vector

$$\vec{v}_P = \vec{v}_C + \omega \times \vec{r} $$
Of course, the question now is how do you take the cross product of a scalar value like $\omega$.
The answer comes from considering the full 3D vectors and proceed with the cross-product as if the rotation are all out of plane vectors.
$$ \pmatrix{ vx_P \\ vy_P \\ 0} = \pmatrix{ vx_C \\ vy_C \\ 0} + \pmatrix{0  \\ 0 \\ \omega} \times \pmatrix{r_x \\ r_y \\ 0} = \pmatrix{ vx_C  - r_y \, \omega \\ vy_C + r_x\, \omega \\ 0} $$

Interestingly, you can find the position $(r_x,r_y)$ that represents the instant center of rotation (which has $\vec{v}_P = 0$) from the equation above
$$ \pmatrix{r_x \\ r_y } = \pmatrix{ \frac{ \mbox{-}vy_C}{\omega} \\ \frac{vx_C}{\omega} }$$
Note that the 3D version of the above is
$$ \vec{r}_{\rm rot} = \frac{ \vec{\omega} \times \vec{v}_C } { \| \vec{\omega} \|^2} $$

Thanks a lot for the nice pictures.

I think I get it, though I was missing how the cross product works with rotations. The way I understand it now is that the velocity component due to rotation is of magnitude $\omega r$ in the direction of the unit vector $\vec{e}{r\perp}$ perpendicular to $\vec{r}$:
$
v_{\text{rot}} = \omega r \vec{e}{r\perp} = \omega r \left(-\frac{r_y}{r} \hat{i} + \frac{r_x}{r} \hat{j}\right) = \omega \left(-r_y \hat{i} + r_x \hat{j}\right)
$

Use the mathematical definition for a cross product $$ \pmatrix{a\b\c} \times \pmatrix{x\y\z} = \pmatrix{b z - c y \ c x - a z \ a y - b x} $$ and set $a=0$, $b=0$ and $c = \omega$ and $z=0$ to project 3D equations into the plane.

Saying that a rigid body as a whole has translational velocity $\mathbf{v}$ is meaningless.
The right description of the motion of a rigid body requires the velocity $\mathbf{v}_P$ of a material point, $P$, and the angular velocity $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ of the rigid body. Given this two quantities, and the relative position of a material point $Q$ w.r.t. the point $P$, $\mathbf{r}_Q - \mathbf{r}_P$, the velocity of the point $Q$ is
$$\mathbf{v}_Q = \mathbf{v}_P + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times (\mathbf{r}_Q - \mathbf{r}_P) \ .$$

Why is that the solution?

https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/Me/rotations/kinematics_rotation.html Look at "Time derivative of Rotation tensor and angular velocity"
